# Multiple update panels in a page each having a custom validator, all fires on a postback

Tags: asp.net, updatepanel, customvalidator

I have a scenario... a page with multiple update panel, each update panel has some controls (with auto postback-on) and custom validator associated with this control.

The problem is... on postback of the control in an update panel, all custom validators in preceeding updatepanels in the page gets fired.

Googling the issue didnot give a clear solution. 
How can i stop this from happening ? Is it a bug or am missing some thing ?

Answer (score 0):

in the updatepanels set up Mode="Conditional" and then declare the triggers for each update panel. This way each update panel is selective in the triggers that will set it to update.

Comment: Thanks. The mode is set to conditional, but still the onValidate method of custom validator fires.  It seems the issue is something to do with the viewstate. but am not able to get through it

Answer (score 0):

how about this solution using validationgroup:

http://simpledotnetsolutions.wordpress.com/2010/12/05/multiple-updatepanels-and-conditional-validation/